# Problem with a Dictionary in a Azure Function: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: location1

Tags: azure, dictionary

This is very strange when I run my Function in VS 22 with no issues.
But when I am in my function Code + Test, Test/Run I enter two parameters, then click run the first time I run the function it works as expected. but if I try to run it again with different parameters I get the dictionary error the item already exists. Is Azure cashing the Dictionary? Even if I leave my function and come back in after a while i still get the same error.

Answer (score -1):

The Azure Function will continue to run after the dictionary has already
been created. So, in my method where I populate the dictionary, I just need to do the following to clear it out:

```
LookDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

New to Azure, and did not think of the Function as running all the time.